# What's the difference between these 2 ways of generating sequences?

Tags: f#

I'm learning about F#, and there are 2 ways of generating sequences that i came across so far, and i'm curious about the differences between them if any.

First way:

```
Seq.unfold(fun x -> Some(x, x + 1)) 1 |> printfn "%A"
```

Second way:

```
Seq.initInfinite (fun x -> x + 1) |> printfn "%A"
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? It explains clearly what each function does, and hence by comparison what's different.

Comment: One of the important differences is that `initInfinite` does just what the name suggests: creates an *infinite* sequence. (Make sure you never try to pass that sequence into a `for` loop, or print the whole thing, without doing a `Seq.take` first!) OTOH, `Seq.unfold` returns a sequence that *might* be infinite if you only ever return `Some` from your function. But if your function ever returns `None`, then that's the end of the sequence, so it'll be finite.

Comment: Another important difference is that `initInfinite` creates elements *independently* while `unfold` does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two key differences between the two:

- First, `unfold` lets you keep some state between steps while `initInfinite` only gives you the index of the item that you are generating, so you need to have a way of producing a value based on the index.
- Second, `unfold` lets you create sequences that are finite (by returning `None`) while `initInfinite` only creates infinite sequences (as the name suggests)

The `unfold` function is more general than `initInfinite`. To see this, we can easily implement `initInfinite` using `unfold`:

```
let initInfinite f = 
  Seq.unfold (fun n -> Some(f n, n + 1)) 0
```

In the other direction, the following example using `unfold` creates a sequence where each element is larger than the previous one by some random number. It ends once the number gets above 100:

```
let rnd = System.Random()
Seq.unfold (fun last -> 
  let next = last + rnd.Next(10)
  if last + next > 100 then None 
  else Some(last + next, last + next) ) 0
```

You cannot do this using `initInfinite` - because you do not know what the previous value was and you cannot end the sequence.